# Get Page Width Javascript - Return PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to do something fairly simple but I am not a good javascript. What I am trying to do is the following:
1. Get the page width via Javascript
2. If Page width is less than 400px then set a php variable to 1

MY JAVASCRIPT IS VERY POOR

```
 //javascript
 var width = $(window).width(); //get the width of the screen
 if (width<400) {
  $slidevar = 1;
   }
```

Then down the page I can get that variable and use it to display my slideshows

```
 //PHP
 if ($slidevar == 1) {
 //Display Slideshow #1 PHP Function
 } else {
 //Display Slideshow #2 PHP Function
 }
```

So this can't be done.

Can you retrieve the page width in PHP one time on page load?

I found this code but how what do I need to do to get my functions?

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script>
  var width = $(window).width();
   //This is ajax code which will send width to your php page in the   screenWidth variable
$.ajax({
url: "example.php", //this will be your php page 
data : {screenwidth:width} 
}).done(function() {
$(this).addClass("done");
});
</script>

//example.php code is here :
<?php
echo $width = $_REQUEST['screenwidth'];
?>
```

Comment: do you know the difference between client side script and server side script and where they run or i say which run first ?

Comment: Ok Yes, and no. Yes PHP is server side and java is client side. So getting variable in PHP cannot be done. Any suggestions on turning off and on a php function using Javascript?

Comment: I should say "Any tricks"? Can you retrieve the page with in PHP?

Comment: You can't use or declare php (Server side) variables inside javascript (Client side). Use ajax to send parameters from jquery to php or vise versa

Comment: if you are familiar with ajax you can check my answer else I will update the answer for ajax call according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery :

```
var width = $(window).width(); //get the width of the screen
if (width<400) {
  var slidevar = 1;
  $.ajax({
    url:"the/php/page",
    data: {'slidevar':slidevar},
    type: 'get',
    success: function(){
       // do something
    }
  });
```

}

php :

```
$slidevar = $_GET['slidevar'];
if ($slidevar == 1) {
  //Display Slideshow #1 PHP Function
} else {
 //Display Slideshow #2 PHP Function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what we can do here to achieve this is

in javascript calculate screen width and make an ajax call to render the slider accordingly

```
var width = screen.width;
if (width < 400) {
   //AJAX call to render slider1
} else {
   //AJAX call to render slider2
}
```